# Is there a way to perform a rollback of transactions in a contract that happened many days ago?

Tags: dapp-development

For the DAO, the only way to rollback was to perform a hard fork.  Has there been any attempts to program code, so that if enough token holders agree, a contract can be rolled back after N+ days, without needing to resort to a hard fork of the entire network.  I'm trying to conceptually think about idiosyncratic solution to rollbacks for specific contracts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge there has not been, but this answer should be updated to reflect so if there has.

This is certainly and purposefully not a feature native to Ethereum so this is something that would have to be implemented.

I think there are three approaches to this:

1. Implement this in a contract that runs in the EVM

   - You could store the delta of all storage changes on the contract
   - Voting could be done in a decentralized manner through this contract
   - It would be expensive to store all state, and make transactions for your users more expensive since they have to pay to store the delta of the state change
2. Store an admin user on your contract and vote and store changes in a centralized server that sends your contract the state that it should revert to.

   - This would be centralized and would mean that the admin user could revert state whenever they would like (bad).
   - This would be incredibly cheap since only one transaction needs to be made to revert state
3. Fork a Cryptocurrency and implement this function natively on the cryptocurrency

   - This is probably the most efficient approach
   - It would mean that any owner of the coins could vote to rollback the state to a certain block number
   - You would have to attract enough miners to run this network.

Answer (score 0):

Technically the DAO wasn't rolled back: There was a once-off state change that moved some funds from one address to another. The history up until that point is still in the blockchain, including the hack.

That said, there are a couple of approaches to doing the social equivalent of a blockchain hard fork, but on the level of an individual token.

One approach is simply to deploy a new contract for the token, with the appropriate balances copied from the appropriate point in history, and ask people to use the new contract instead of the old one. This can work well if the token contract only manages itself and does not control any external assets, in particular ETH. There's some discussion of that approach [in this piece](https://medium.com/@edmundedgar/what-happens-when-you-try-to-fork-an-ethereum-token-863e3defcf7).

Another approach is to actually manage the history in the contract, and have a process to decide on what version of the history should be preferred. This is usually not preferred because it tends to add complexity and gas expense, but it can be done. At a minimum you need some way of tracking the changes so that you can prove to the contract what it looked like at a particular point.

For reference, [this contract](https://github.com/realitykeys/subjectivocracy/blob/master/contracts/RealityToken.sol) manages credits and debits on an infinite number of branches; If you had a process to decide on which one was valid, you could use it to perform rollbacks. Alternatively you might keep a record of every transaction in storage, so that you can then rerun them backwards if the tokenholder vote process approves. This will be expensive, so to get the same outcome at lower cost, you could store a single hash in the contract, representing the entire chain of transactions in the contract's history; With each transaction, hash the content of the current transaction and the previous hash. If the tokenholder vote permits, this can then be played back by any user supplying the history in reverse order, as we do (for a different purpose) [in this contract](https://bitbucket.org/edmundedgar/realitycheck/src/f6f12e3996dd5ce42b4ed53727ce19e782d47332/truffle/contracts/RealityCheck.sol?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#RealityCheck.sol-443).